# Xcode won't commit after update to 8

Tags: ios, xcode, github, commit, xcode8

I Updated my Xcode to Xcode 8.0 yesterday, and my project won't commit. When i go to Source Control > Commit : It shows no files and so i can't press the commit button.

Here's how it looks like :

[image]

And here's what my "git status" says :

On branch Master
Your branch is ahead of 'Github/Master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)

```
modified:   MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
modified: MyProject.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/SkkN.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/MyProject.xcscheme
modified:   MyProject/AppDelegate.swift
modified:   MyProject/AuthenticationController.swift
modified:   MyProject/BaseController.swift
modified:   MyProject/Button.swift
modified:   MyProject/Checklist.swift
modified:   MyProject/ChecklistCell.swift
modified:   MyProject/ContentCell.swift
modified:   MyProject/ContentsList.swift
modified:   MyProject/ControlBar.swift
modified:   MyProject/DashboardController.swift
modified:   MyProject/DescriptionView.swift
modified:   MyProject/DropdownMenu.swift
modified:   MyProject/DropdownMenuCell.swift
modified:   MyProject/IconLabel.swift
modified:   MyProject/ImageButton.swift
modified:   MyProject/Info.plist
modified:   MyProject/Label.swift
modified:   MyProject/MenuCell.swift
modified:   MyProject/NavigationBar.swift
modified:   MyProject/NavigationMenu.swift
modified:   MyProject/NotificationBar.swift
modified:   MyProject/NotificationsButton.swift
modified:   MyProject/PopUp.swift
modified:   MyProjectHoop/ProfileController.swift
modified:   MyProject/ProfileTab.swift
modified:   MyProject/ProfileTabsView.swift
modified:   MyProject/StorageCell.swift
modified:   MyProject/StorageChart.swift
modified:   MyProject/StorageView.swift
modified:   MyProject/SummaryCell.swift
modified:   MyProject/SummaryView.swift
modified:   MyProject/TextButton.swift
modified:   MyProject/TextField.swift
modified:   MyProject/Tools.swift
```

Untracked files:
  (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

```
.gitattributes
.gitignore
MyProject.xcworkspace/
MyProject/Activity.swift
MyProject/ActivityLog.swift
MyProject/ActivityLogCell.swift
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/ActivityDayIcon.imageset/
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/ActivityFirstDayIcon.imageset/
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/ActivityIcon.imageset/
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-40.png
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-40@2x.png
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-40@3x.png
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-60@2x.png
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-60@3x.png
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-76.png
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-76@2x.png
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-83.5@2x.png
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-Small.png
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-Small@2x.png
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Icon-Small@3x.png
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/Background.imageset/Background.png
MyProject/Assets.xcassets/DummyCompanyLogo.imageset/
MyProject/DropDownList.swift
MyProject/FontCell.swift
MyProject/FontLibraryTab.swift
MyProject/FontList.swift
MyProject/GeneralInfosTab.swift
MyProject/MyProject-Bridging-Header.h
MyProject/ManageDataTab.swift
MyProject/NotificationsChecklist.swift
MyProject/OpeningHoursPopUp.swift
MyProject/ProfileActivityTab.swift
MyProject/ProfileNotificationsTab.swift
MyProject/SecurityTab.swift
MyProject/SettingsController.swift
MyProject/SettingsNotificationsTab.swift
MyProject/SettingsTabsView.swift
MyProject/TabsView.swift
MyProject/WeekdaysTab.swift
Podfile
Podfile.lock
```

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Please help.

---

UPDATE 1

I tried to replicate the error, and it is happening in my older projects too. With a new project (alone or inside an old workspace) Xcode reports correctly the status of the files, and commit is possible.

*(I'm now trying to find why git-commit is not possible from inside Xcode in old projects...)*

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Good news is your version control is there. Bad news is you need to `git add` them.

Comment: You mean i have to 'git add' every file in the 2nd list ? (every file except those I don't want to share) ?

Comment: Yes. But you can do them all with `git add .` and remove unwanted files with `git rm` later.

Comment: I did that, but i still not see any file when i go to Source Control > Commit. What should i do ?

Comment: You can try to add your repo to Xcode from Xcode accounts preferences.

Comment: It's already there :(

Comment: I wouldn't depend on XCode repo tools. You should try open source apps like Tower or SourceTree. They blackbox many tricks that you can do from terminal. You can also use terminal to manage your source code. More control and better understand what's happening. In this case you should type `git add .` then `git commit -m "your message here"` and `git push`.

Comment: Whyy don't we try Source Tree?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any solution, so I've installed Xcode 7.3.1

So now i use Xcode 8.0 to code, and i open Xcode 7.3.1 to commit and push to my Github repository. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `Terminal` to commit, pull & push your code.

To perform that follow below steps:

1. Open `Terminal`
2. `cd path_where_your_repository_is_locally`
3. `git status` - To check the status
4. `git add -A` - To add all the files which are modified or newly added.
5. `git commit -m "Your Commit Message"`
6. `git pull origin Branch` - To get the code which you don't have & is committed by some other developer.
7. `git push origin Branch` - To push your code & files to server.

That's it. Hope this helps.